# Hardware accelerated FFmpeg on android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, live-wallpaper, hardware-acceleration, video-codecs

I compiled an older version of FFmpeg for Android (if I recall correctly it was 0.6.X). FFmpeg decodes a video frame, scales it, then I'm using OpenGL to draw it on the screen. As far as I can tell, the problem is the decoding and scaling---they're not hardware accelerated.

My question is:

1. Is the latest version of FFmpeg hardware accelerated for ARM (Android) processors?
2. Am I going about this the wrong way? i.e., is there a better way of doing this? Where "this" is playing a h264 HD video as a video live wallpaper---the framerate needs to be high, so hardware acceleration is desirable whenever available.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think so , yes. see : http://ffmpeg.org/#pr9  .
   the major release that has the hardware accelerated decoding of h264 on Android is Harmony 0.9
2. if you use a decoder that takes advantage of the hardware acceleration, when it's available, I don't see how you can do better...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is ffmpeg compiled for ARM NEON. See:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/mGF6t3uWZ4U

Comment: not quite. That allows ffmpeg to run on an ARM NEON (which I already did). But it does not enable hardware accelaration (different things). thanks for the reply

Comment: hold on. what do you mean by hardware acceleration for FFMPEG then? FFMPEG "hardware acceleration" doesn't make sense(if you don't mean NEON). or Did you mean hardware acceleration for OpenGL? I hope you are rendering your video using vertex buffer objects(VBO's) or shaders(to get hardware acceleration). I think your choke point is OpenGl rendering and not ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try compiling ffmpeg with libstagefright_h264, I was able to get it to compile and read video file properties, but have been unable to get avcodec_open to work with it... That would be hardware accelerated assuming it was supported by the device.