# Android ffmpeg and hardware acceleration

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I want my video streaming application to utilize hardware acceleration in android.
I'm limited to udp video broadcasting so I can't use Android media player, so I plan to use ffmpeg.
Is there a way to make ffmpeg utilize hardware acceleration on android ?

Comment: I have similar problem, I've done some research and found [these examples](http://www.splitted-desktop.com/static/libva/hwdecode-demos/) most useful, but I'm still not 100% sure how to do that and would like to see someone with more experience to write minimal hardware accelerated player to show us how that is made.

Comment: GSoC 2011 had a project, [Hardware Accelerated H264 Decoding on Android](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=FFmpeg_Summer_Of_Code#Hardware_Accelerated_H264_Decoding_on_Android)

Comment: What about other codecs? BSPlayer seems to be able to do hardware accelerated decoding on Android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869907/hardware-accelerated-ffmpeg-on-android

Answer (score 1):

Seems ffmpeg since 0.9 supports it http://freecode.com/projects/ffmpeg/releases/339441

How exactly to use/enable it, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using stagefright along with ffmpeg. You can refer [this](https://vec.io/posts/use-android-hardware-decoder-with-omxcodec-in-ndk). Summary:
 1. Get the android source download and build it.(refer [this](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html))
 2. Get ffmpeg source download and build.
 3. Use ffmpeg and stagefright to use android h/w decoder.